# Variable holds value in memory between DLL calls

Tags: c++, dll

I have a DLL written in C++ that is called by a Windows application multiple times during a simulation. When I execute a simulation, the DLL is loaded into memory once at the beginning and is not unloaded until the end of the simulation. During a simulation, a function in the DLL is called many times. I want an output of the DLL function to be reused as input to the same function on each successive call so that I can calculate a running total. My thought was that I just need to define a global variable outside the function then I can refer to it and add to it each time the function is called but it seems that the global variable is not saving the updated value. Instead it appears to reset to 0 each time the DLL is called.

Here is my DLL function call, which is working just fine except for the global variable:

```
double Revenue = 0;   //global variable

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) CashFlow(int methodID, int* status, double* inargs, double* outargs)
{
    Bank MyBank1(methodID, inargs, outargs, Revenue);
    *status = MyBank1.UpdateAmounts();

    Revenue = MyBank1.getRevenue();
}
```

Can you please tell me what I might be doing wrong or how I might be able to define a global variable that stores persistent data in my DLL?

Thank you!

Comment: Global variable should work exactly the way you expect it to. Something is going on beyond your description.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you have two global variables named Revenue, one in the DLL and one in your own module because you declared it in the .h file.  A somewhat typical mishap induced by assuming it would be a workaround for having to add a GetRevenue() function.  It isn't.

Comment: Global state is bad practice. Eschew. Add an argument and a return type to your function, let the user call `revenue = CashFlow(...,...,revenue);`